# Integration using interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Consider the formula :

$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+h} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=K_1hf(a+h)+error term$$

1/ Find $K_1$ by polynomial interpolation.

2/ Find the Taylor expansion of the error term when $h\to 0$ and predict the polynomial order on the error term basis.

1/ we approximate f|[a,a+h] using a single interpolation point $[a+h]$ : 
$p(x)=f(a+h)$

$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+h} f(x) dx \, \mathrm{d} \approx \int_{a}^{a+h}p(x) dx = f(a+h)[a+h-a]=h*f(a+h)$

So we have $K_1$=1.

2/ $p(h)=f(a+h)$

The Taylor expansion is : $p(h)=f(a)+f'(a)*h+f"(a)*h²/2+....$

$\displaystyle I(h)=\int_{a}^{a+h} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

The Taylor expansion is :

$I(h)=0+f(a)h+f'(a)*h/2+....$

The error term is :
$I(h)-p(h)=0+f(a)h+f'(a)*h/2-f(a)-f'(a)*h-f"(a)*h²/2$

The error should be in h, but here the leading term is f(a) !! as h tends to 0?
I don't know where is the mistake

Thanks

Comment: You should use the point $(a+h)$ to do your Taylor expansion.

Comment: I don't get it ???

Comment: Write $f(x)=f(a+h)+f'(a+h)(x-a-h)+...$. Use this to do the integration and compute the error term.

Comment: If I do that I will have that  $ error = |\displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+h} f(a+h)-f(a+h)+f'(a+h)(x-a-h)+... \, \mathrm{d}x|=|f'(a+h)(-h²/2)|=f'(a+h)h²/2$ The error is in h², isn't it supposed to be in h ?

Comment: It is correct. It is in $h^2$ in this subinterval. The cumulative error is in $h$ if your interval is $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !